# Using EF and Linq and exclude properties in a select statement

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

The methods are created via Entity Framework and Linq in VS2012 and C#,
as such, I want to call a model named `Categories`.
Each category, has a `parentID` (either null or set), which encounts for multiplicity.
Thus, we have 1 parent Category, and that category has Children of categories, a

```
System.Data.Objects.DataClasses.EntityCollection<< Category >>
```

However, each category has a single property which contains a massive load of data, we only want to load that specific property on the parent.
Current code is:

```
selectedCategory = categoryObjectContext.Category.Single<Category>(cat => cat.CategoryID == selectedID);
```

Comment: what is the exact question??

Comment: Sorry, the question would be: how can I select the parent, and get the children, but only get selective properties for the children back, not the entire child's class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to project the results from your query using `.Select()` and use a `Where()` clause to filter the data:

```
int parentID = categoryObjectContext.Category.Where(cat => cat.CategoryID == selectedID)
                   .Select(cat => cat.parentID) // Project the query results into a single field
                   .First(); // This will only select one column
```

Comment: Great stuff! Though, how can I get the parent that way? Selecting the parent will still fill all the children automatically.

Comment: You can select any properties of the Category within the `Select` statement and only the ones selected will be pulled back, e.g. `.Select(cat => cat.parent.parentCategoryName)` only pulls back the string for the parent category name. `.Select(cat => cat.parent)` selects the entire parent

Comment: Well there lies the problem, selecting the parent will cause the same issue.
The parent holds a property array of children, which, again, holds an aweful lot of data within each child. Maybe I should add I want the children, just don't want every property of them.

Comment: @JohnW I understand, but there really is no limit to what you can do with `.Select()`, you just need to tailor it to your requirement. If I understand correctly: `.Select(cat => cat.parent.children.Select(child => new { child.Id, child.Name })` will select only the ID and Name of each child on the parent category